# ioProx ID card continually getting fried

Tags: rfid

My work uses ioProx proximity ID badges to get into the building, whose specs can be found [here](http://securimetric.net/library/61_DS_ioProx_Cards_1616_EN_L-1.pdf). We use the P10SHL.

My card is continually getting fried. I have gone through about 8 cards in a three year period, and my last card only lasted two weeks. The culprits are probably my cell phone and wireless car keys.

I'll be getting a new cell phone this summer, but in the meantime, is there anything I can do to shield the card to prevent it from getting fried?

Comment: *The culprits are probably my cell phone and wireless car keys.* - Based on what, exactly?  It's extremely unlikely that these are to blame; they're not only much lower power than the card readers but also operating at a completely different frequency.  I'm inclined to believe that this is a mechanical problem, which would be off-topic.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Just based on they're wireless devices in close proximity to my card all day. When you say mechanical, do you mean cracks and large bends in the card?

Comment: Not necessarily in the card plastic, rather problems in the hair-thin copper wires inside the card.  A temporary bend could do it, vibration could do it, water ingress could do it, a sharp shock could do it...you don't have to see damage on the outside.

Comment: Cellphone maybe - depends on card technology. Car key sender - extremely unlikely. Are other people experiencing failures?

Comment: Hi Russell. An unscientific polling of the people in group tells me that I am having way more failures than the rest of them. I will probably take Kevin's advice and get a sturdy sleeve so that the card doesn't bend. And if that doesn't work I can blame it on the cell phone and get a new phone.

Comment: Have you called Tech support for an RMA ? Ask for a Failure Analysis . Toll free: 1-888-KANTECH (1-888-526-8324) www.kantech.com Ask if they did any Cell phone EMC tests for ingress damage to cards. Your Cell phone transmits even in receive mode every few minutes. Use separate pockets for now. Only issue I've heard (no pun) is the speakers in cars.. resonate with the modulation of Tx power. during Standby Sync to tower. (ever few minutes) or mics high Z with poor shld pick it up on PC's